# WPF forms+ Winforms in MDI

Tags: wpf

We have an application which is using winforms. Now we want to upgrade it.
We are planning to use some WPF forms and some old winforms. and we also need to use MDI.

From MDIParent we need to open both winforms and WPF forms. And these forms need to be in tile format. I got to know that WPF doesn't support MDI.

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Using AvalonDock, can we display the forms in tiles format also. I know that it display in Dockable format.

Comment: Follow link : Might help you. This solved my prob.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044618/set-wpf-parent-to-a-mdiform

Answer (score 0):

why you want to upgrade your application to wpf and still use some of your old winforms and the mdi concept any further?(i dont like mixup both:))
for quick and dirty what about using your winform app and integrate wpf in it - if you want/have to?

EDIT:
if you want your WinForms in Wpf you can use

```
<WindowsFormsHost />
```

It should work with Avalon too. Here is an example for [WindowsFormsHost](http://www.codegod.biz/WebAppCodeGod/Integration-of-WinForms-in-WPF-Applications-AID405.aspx).

Comment: Its a very large application, so they dont want to convert all the forms to wpf. Is it possible to do or not? In AvalonDock can we use winforms as well? And the forms need to be displayed in tiles format