# Set Wpf parent to a MDIform

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I have a win form application with a `MDI Form`.

for some reason i used a `WPF Window` in my application.
so i want to ask how can i set WPF window parent to my MDI Form?

Comment: There's no good way to make a WPF window an MDI child window.  It doesn't have the required plumbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should give you the ability to set the owner of the wpf dialog to your win form.

```
public static void SetOwner(System.Windows.Forms.Form owner, System.Windows.Window wpfWindow)
    {
        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(wpfWindow);
        helper.Owner = owner.Handle;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `open-source MDI implementation for WPF` that you might want to look at. It may be a good bit of work and re-structuring of your code, but if you absolutely must have MDI, then that may be the best way to go forward with this - [MDI for WPF](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/).